# Quero pegar somente o primeiro digito apos o ponto de um numero isso em python 3.7.4

Tags: python, ponto-flutuante

Quero pegar somente o numero apos o ponto, tipo no numero 3.76443 quero imprimir somente o 7, como faço? como vou fazer também para imprimi-lo? tenho que criar uma variável para ele?

Comment: Multiplique por 10 e transforme em int e daí egue o resto da divisão por 10.

Answer (score 2):

Conforme sugestão do anonimo, multiplique por 10 e pegue o resto da divisão por 10 ignorando os decimais. Ao multiplicar `3.76443` por 10 o número vira `37.6443`, o resto da divisão por 10 é `7.6443`. Use `%` para pegar o resto da divisão e `int()` para desconsiderar os decimais.

Código:

```
i=3.76443
print(int(i*10%10))
```

Resultado:

> 7

Veja funcionando no Ideone: https://ideone.com/c7Z7Up

Answer (score 0):

vc pode fazer tanto matematicamente ou com conversão de tipos, nesse caso convertendo para string e fazer a edição

```
n = 3.76443
ns = str(n)
ponto = ns.find('.')
print(ns[ponto+1])

n1 = n - int(n)
n1 *= 10
n1 = int(n1)
print(n1)
```

Comment: nao teria como pegar esse numero usando o round ou o % tratando ele como numero?

Comment: o round vai arredondar, no numero de exemplo, ele arredonda para 3.8, fazer a divisão com % sera preciso usa o numero convertido para int, ou seja mais contas a se fazer, ñ vejo pq querer complicar

Answer (score 0):

Segue da maneira mais simples que consegui imaginar:

```
 numero = 3.76443
 print(str(numero).split('.')[1][0])
```

Primeiro transforma a variável em string **str(numero)**, depois divide ela no ponto  **.split('.')** como você quer, depois pega só a parte após o ponto **[1]** e depois o primeiro index que existe após o ponto **[0]**.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser importar a biblioteca `math` dá para fazer o seguinte:

```
import math

numero = 3.76443
fracao=math.modf(numero)
fracao=str(fracao[0])
print(fracao[2])
```

No caso acima Using você vai estar usando a função `modf()` que resulta em uma tupla que divide a fração. Nessa tupla o número "quebrado" fica na posição 0 e o inteiro na posição 1.

Sem usar a math (e já contornando o problema do número seguinte ao ponto ser 0), mas com um código mais extenso:

```
numero = 3.76443
text = "{:.1f}".format(numero)
if text.endswith(".0"):
    text = text[:-2]
```